# Can a fixed width website be made responsive using media queries?

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a website. It is fixed width. I am looking for some tutorials to make it responsive without me making it fluid. Is it possible? Can I use **media queries** to make mobile/tab/touch device compatible websites without making much changes to the current HTML files (as there are many) but by modifying CSS?

Comment: I think this [blog post](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries) explains how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if you have found a good solution already, but I do want to add something.

If you are familiar with the [960](http://960.gs) grid system I bet you will like the [skeleton grid](http://getskeleton.com). The 960 grid system is just a normal css framework that is fixed at 960 px width. The skeleton grid ads 2 more fixed states to this.

The nice thing IMO is that they are fixed states, they pop into place at browser resize instead of fluid changing.

I am also working a lot with responsive designs, and I find the fluid grids ugly. I like to have fixed states. I think it is much cleaner, and easier to work with.

--

I myself work with my own grid that is a combination. It has a base of 960px, this is for medium screens and browser that do not support mediaqueries.

I extend this with one bigger state of **1140px** for bigger screen. After that is the default state of **960px**. After that is pops into a state of **768px**, next **480px**, and finally **320px**.

That makes 5 states, with state 4 as it's default. It works great, and I am baking it into a blank WordPress theme that I will use for all my projects.